# How to determine if an option in lightning-checkbox-group in LWC is unchecked

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-checkbox-group

How do I determine which checkbox in a lightning-checkbox-group is unchecked? I want to filter results based on selected checkbox.

I have tried using both lines below in the onchange event

```
handleIssueAreas(e) {    
        this.issueValue = e.detail.value;
       console.log('issue value '+ this.issueValue);
        
        if(this.issueValue){
                       
            this.searchArray.push(this.issueValue);
            const payload = { searchString: this.searchArray};

            publish(this.messageContext, SEARCH_MESSAGE, payload);
            
        }
        else if(!this.issueValue ){
            
            console.log('Unchecked!' );
            //add the logic here
        }
      
    }
```

```
 console.log('checked value ' + e.target.checked);
 console.log('checked value ' + e.detail.checked);
```

but they are both returning undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the documentation for the [lightning-checkbox-group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example) demonstrates exactly how to do so, code snippet included as well as usage notes. Since you have not shared your template or JS file, it's hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

to get checked values onchange, you can use:

```
e.detail.value
```

this will create an array of selecte values which you can use to do whatever.

Comment: I already did that. As you can see in the code updated above. However, the else part is not getting executed when I uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @Pauline, as mentioned in my answer, this will create an array of selected values which you can use to do whatever. Your code does not make any sense, you are checking for an array, and then pushing your array into another array. you are also checking for the checked property, which is non-existent...

Comment: The rest of the code is quite long that is why i did not put it here. There are two components involved. one has several checkbox groups and once a selection is made, the checkbox values are published. So I got the publishing part to work with by getting the e.detail.value.

Comment: the second component receives the values and does the filtering. However, the unchecking part is what is not working. I need to send the message on the unchecked checkbox so that i adjust the results on the second component.

Comment: you can check the values from the array, if the value is missing, you handle accordingly.  not sure what issue you are facing.

Comment: I have tried to print the value of e.detail.value after unchecking and used that in the condition. But on unchecking, it just returns all the search values.

Comment: your original question `How to determine if an option in lightning-checkbox-group in LWC is unchecked` has been answered -> if the value is not in the array, it means that it is not checked. If you have another issue, I would suggest you open a new question in order to avoid an extended discussion,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123943/discussion-between-pauline-and-glls).